# How can I modify this code chunk to recode all ~400 variables in my dataframe and not just one?

Tags: r, dplyr, dummy-variable

I wrote this in R to dummy code a character variable that consists of either "0" or a character response (like "sh6sej"), so that all character responses go to 1 and all 0's go to 0. It works fine for the one variable.

However, is there a way to modify this so it dummy codes all 400 variables in my dataframe at once?

Thank you!

```
recode_mut <- function(var = "adgra2_mut", data=data_train) {
   recoded <- ifelse(data_train[[var]] == 0, 0,
                           ifelse(data_train[[var]] != 0, 1, NA))
   return(recoded)
}

recode_mut(var = "adgra2_mut")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `mutate` with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
out <- data_train %>%
     mutate(across(everything(), ~ as.integer(. != 0)))
```

---

Or use `base R`

```
out <- as.data.frame(+(data_train != 0))
```